# Binding escape-j prefix in tmux conflicts with neovim

Tags: macos, neovim, tmux

When I set `escape-j` as prefix in tmux, I have to wait when pressing escape in nvim.

What I have done:

I bind `escape-j` as my prefix in tmux with:

```
set -g prefix M-j
unbind C-b
bind-key M-j send-prefix
```

However when I do so, I have to wait 500ms when pressing `escape` in nvim to go back to normal mode.
so I tried to set

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

It indeed fixes the problem in nvim, but I can't use the tmux commands with prefix anymore, which makes sense.

How to fix so that this combination works?

---

I was also interested in mapping `cmd` instead of escape, but I can't find how to bind `cmd-j`

*Note*: caps lock is set to escape in my MacOS settings